# how to get user data from facebook login in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am very new in Windows Phone 8.1 Apps development. I am developing an app in which I want facebook and google plus integration. I have to get the user data from those logins. I tried to get the data from Facebook but I am getting an error 
**Success
SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.**
Please can anyone help me out to solve this issue. I saw many links regarding this, but this did not solved. I have also associated the app with Windows Store.

**Facebook Helper Class**

```
    using Facebook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;

namespace FacebookIntegration

{
    public class FaceBookHelper
    {

    FacebookClient _fb = new FacebookClient();
    readonly Uri _callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
    readonly Uri _loginUrl;
    private const string FacebookAppId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";//Enter your FaceBook App ID here  
    //private const string FacebookPermissions = "user_about_me,read_stream,publish_stream";
    private const string FacebookPermissions = "user_about_me";
    public string AccessToken
    {
        get { return _fb.AccessToken; }
    }

    public FaceBookHelper()
    {
        _loginUrl = _fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = FacebookAppId,
            //redirect_uri = _callbackUri.AbsoluteUri,
            redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
            scope = FacebookPermissions,
            display = "popup",
            response_type = "token"
        });
        //Debug.WriteLine(_callbackUri);//This is useful for fill Windows Store ID in Facebook WebSite  
    }
    private void ValidateAndProccessResult(WebAuthenticationResult result)
    {
        if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            var responseUri = new Uri(result.ResponseData.ToString());
            var facebookOAuthResult = _fb.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(responseUri);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(facebookOAuthResult.Error))
                _fb.AccessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
            else
            {//error de acceso denegado por cancelación en página  
            }
        }
        else if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
        {// error de http  
        }
        else
        {
            _fb.AccessToken = null;//Keep null when user signout from facebook  
        }
    }
    public void LoginAndContinue()
    {
        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(_loginUrl);
    }
    public void ContinueAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        ValidateAndProccessResult(args.WebAuthenticationResult);
    }  
}
```

}

**ContinuationManager Class**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace FacebookIntegration
{
    class ContinuationManager
    {
        public void ContinueWith(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
            return;

        switch (args.Kind)
        {
            case ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation:
                break;
            case ActivationKind.PickFolderContinuation:
                break;
            case ActivationKind.PickSaveFileContinuation:
                break;
            case ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation:
                var continuator = rootFrame.Content as IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable;
                if (continuator != null)
                    continuator.ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker((WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs)args);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }  
}
interface IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuable
{
    void ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args);
}
```

}

**In MainPage.Xaml.cs Class**

I Have added :

```
FaceBookHelper ObjFBHelper = new FaceBookHelper();
    FacebookClient fbclient = new FacebookClient(); 

private void BtnFaceBookLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObjFBHelper.LoginAndContinue();
    }

    public async void ContinueWithWebAuthenticationBroker(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        ObjFBHelper.ContinueAuthentication(args);
        if (ObjFBHelper.AccessToken != null)
        {
            fbclient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(ObjFBHelper.AccessToken);

            //Fetch facebook UserProfile:  
            dynamic result = await fbclient.GetTaskAsync("me");
            string id = result.id;
            string email = result.email;
            string FBName = result.name;

            //Format UserProfile:  
            GetUserProfilePicture(id);
            TxtUserProfile.Text = FBName;
            StckPnlProfile_Layout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            BtnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            BtnLogout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            StckPnlProfile_Layout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }


    private void GetUserProfilePicture(string UserID)
    {
        string profilePictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type={1}&access_token={2}", UserID, "square", ObjFBHelper.AccessToken);
        picProfile.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(profilePictureUrl));
    }
```

**In MainPage.Xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
        <!--Title-->
        <TextBlock Text="FaceBook Integration in WP8.1:" FontSize="28" Foreground="Gray"/>
        <!--Buttons for Login & Logout-->
        <Button Name="BtnLogin" Content="FaceBook Login" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF00A9CF" Click="BtnFaceBookLogin_Click"/>
        <Button Visibility="Collapsed" Name="BtnLogout" Content="FaceBook Logout" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF00A9CF" />

        <StackPanel Visibility="Collapsed" Name="StckPnlProfile_Layout">
            <!--Display facebook profile info-->
            <TextBlock Text="User Profile :" FontSize="30" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="White"/>
            <Image Stretch="None" x:Name="picProfile"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Name="TxtUserProfile" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="White"/>
            <!--Post wall-->
            <TextBox Name="TxtStatusMsg" MinHeight="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Header="Status Message:" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black"/>
            <Button Content="Post Status on FaceBook" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF00A9CF" />
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to develop this app. I have created this app as an Universal app. Anyone please help me out to solve this issue quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure your application is live on facebook  [link] (https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Comment: get detailed information from following  http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html

Comment: its your redirect_uri.